# Get attribute from table - Protractor

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I have a table with multiple TR row, I need to be able to click on `<tr>` or any `child <td>` where VALUE is 91, In this example below there are just 2 values, but in a future there can be a 20 of them, and they can be differently sort as well.

Is there a way I can FIND a value from this below and click on that element?

```
<td class="ultranarrow ng-binding">91</td>
```

Table HTML:

```
                       <tbody>
                        <!-- end ngRepeat: row in gridData | filter:gridFilter --><tr ng-click="toggle(row)" ng-repeat="row in gridData | filter:gridFilter" ng-class="{
                                selected: row.selected,
                                selectable: row.selectable,
                                'text-danger': !row.selectable,
                                modified: row.modified
                            }" class="ng-scope selectable">
                            <td class="minimal text-center">
                                <!-- ngIf: row.selectable --><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok dehover ng-scope text-disabled" ng-class="'text-' + (row.selected ? 'primary' : 'disabled')" ng-if="row.selectable"></a><!-- end ngIf: row.selectable -->
                            </td>
                            <td class="ultranarrow ng-binding">91</td>
                            <td class="ng-binding">Spoluúčast (dokumentace)</td>
                            <td class="narrow">
                                <!-- ngIf: row.selected -->
                            </td>
                            <td class="ultranarrow ng-binding">KČ</td>
                        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: row in gridData | filter:gridFilter --><tr ng-click="toggle(row)" ng-repeat="row in gridData | filter:gridFilter" ng-class="{
                                selected: row.selected,
                                selectable: row.selectable,
                                'text-danger': !row.selectable,
                                modified: row.modified
                            }" class="ng-scope selectable">
                            <td class="minimal text-center">
                                <!-- ngIf: row.selectable --><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok dehover ng-scope text-disabled" ng-class="'text-' + (row.selected ? 'primary' : 'disabled')" ng-if="row.selectable"></a><!-- end ngIf: row.selectable -->
                            </td>
                            <td class="ultranarrow ng-binding">95</td>
                            <td class="ng-binding">Předcházející poškození (výpočet)</td>
                            <td class="narrow">
                                <!-- ngIf: row.selected -->
                            </td>
                            <td class="ultranarrow ng-binding">KČ</td>
                        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: row in gridData | filter:gridFilter -->
                    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[xpath](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.xpath) is your friend when you need exact value matching. This should do the trick:

```
element.all(by.xpath('.//td[.="91" and @class="ultranarrow ng-binding"]')).click();
```

Comment: Hi @dmitankin, your answer is definitly logical. just click TD where value is 91 and class is one I want to. Unfortunately it doesnt work for me. 
Protractor didnt throw any error but freez a bit when trying to click this.

First I think it can be because it didnt see 91 at start (need to scroll down) so i pick second option, dispite this fact it didnt select specific TD :)

Comment: Hi @Andurit, I forgot about the xpath context and modified the answer appropriately. Sorry. Now it selects all such `td` elements in the document. You can easily constrain it to your table by [element chaining](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md#finding-sub-elements)